# Desktop Computer went Black but holding the power button didn't turn it off

Tags: windows-10, desktop-computer, noise

Yesterday, i was watching some videos on the web, when all of a sudden my computer started making weird noises (*precise location undeterminable, but i suspect the liquid cooler*), the screens all went out at the same time, but the computer kept running. I tried holding the power button to turn it off, but even after a minute it didn't turn off so i switched off the PSU and it finally turned off.

If the cooler was defective then it would softly turn off in an attempt to preserve itself, and not just die like that and keep running...

Summarized flow of events:

1. Noise from (*probably*) Fan/Pump
2. Spontaneous Blackout
3. Computer hardware buttons stop responding

I have since started to suspect the MB could be dying/ded, but i am not sure. Do you guys have any idea as to what could be causing this or these problems?

Comment: Sounds like your PSU... Otherwise it is hard to say from the amount of information.

Comment: @tukan well, you might actually be onto something, i just remembered that my PSU *was* unusually hot when i inspected it yesterday thought at that time i didn't pay much attention to it as i was more focused on the fan noise...

Comment: If so I would replace the PSU ASAP.  Do not try to switch on the computer.

Comment: @tukan i will do this as a first step, see if it fixes the problem

Comment: Also -- noises from the **liquid** cooler? Any leak into the system?